# Measurable set on which a function is bounded

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ be in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, $\mathbb{R}$ the real numbers. Show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $A \subseteq R$ , measurable, such that $m(A) < \infty$ , $f$ is bounded on $A$ and $ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f|  < \int_{A} |f| + \varepsilon$.

If we take $A$ as the support of the simple function which approximates $f$ in the $L^{1}$ norm then this has finite measure and it satisfies the other conditions. But I don't see why $f$ must be bounded on it. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: @user100: take a sequence of functions converging pointwise to $f$ which *are* bounded (e.g., $f_n$ equal to $f$ if the values are between $-n$ and $n$, and either $-n$ or $n$ otherwise), then approximate $f$ with some bounded function and the bounded function with a simple function. I haven't worked out the details, so this may very well crash and burn...

Answer (score 7):

You can do this as a "$2\epsilon$-proof" (or $\epsilon/2$ if you prefer).  First, since $(\int_{-n}^n|f|)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|$, there is an $n$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|\lt\int_{-n}^n|f|+\epsilon/2$.  Then, since $(\int_{-n}^n|f|\cdot\chi_{\{|f|\leq m\}})_{m=1}^\infty$ converges to $\int_{-n}^n|f|$, there is an $m$ such that $\int_{-n}^n|f|\lt\int_{-n}^n|f|\cdot\chi_{\{|f|\leq m\}}+\epsilon/2$.  Take $A=[-n,n]\cap\{x:|f(x)|\leq m\}$.

Rather than using simple functions to show this, I would use this as a first step to showing that $f$ can be approximated by simple functions, because now $f$ can be uniformly approximated by simple functions on $A$.

Comment: (The 2 steps aren't really necessary, and you could just use the fact that $|f|\cdot \chi_{\{x\in[-n,n]:|f(x)|\leq n\}}$ converges to $|f|$ pointwise a.e.)

Comment: @user100: If you like it you should approve the answer :)

Comment: @user100: You're welcome.  Of course this is just a sketch, and justification is needed for the 2 claims of convergence.  For example, monotone or dominated convergence can be used.

Answer (score 3):

$|f|I_{|f|\leq n} $ increases to $|f|I_{|f| < \infty} = |f|$ (a.e.) as $f$ is in $L^{1}(\mathcal{R})$, the result follows from monotone convergence theorem.

Update : This answer is incomplete, please see Jonas's answer.

Comment: Sorry for the overlap.  I was still getting the TeX to work when your answer was posted.  Your answer would have to be modified to get $m(A)\lt\infty$.